# Electron renders blank page once I implemented vue-router

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuejs3, vue-router

I am currently building app using Vue3 and Electron.
But once I implemented vue-router, I can only see blank page.

I installed vue3 and electron separately.
If I only render component not router view, then it's totally fine.

Here is my approach.

```
vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/"),
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    }
  }
})
```

```
main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  win.loadFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);
  win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
});
```

```
Vue/main.js
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

```
router.js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

import LoginPage from '../pages/LoginPage.vue';
import RegisterPage from '../pages/RegisterPage.vue';
import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: LoginPage
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    component: RegisterPage
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomePage
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router;
```

When I run the app I can see only blank page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On builds, Electron only works with hash routing. You need to replace [`createWebHistory()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#Functions-createWebHistory) with [`createWebHashHistory()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#Functions-createWebHashHistory).

Comment: Wow, this just made my default page / show on my Electron + Vue + Vite setup. Thanks!